# the_post_thumbnail() doesn't always return selected size

Tags: post-thumbnails

In my theme's archive template, I'm using

```
the_post_thumbnail('list-thumb-small');
```

to get a specific thumbnail size for each post. But that doen's work on all posts. Some posts display their featured image in full size, while others display the correct "list-thumb-small" size.

I have set the custom image size in functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'list-thumb-small', 225, 185, true );
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those might be old images. Image uploaded to WordPress before adding this new image size code will not resize automatically. You will have to resize old images again.

There is a great plugin for that. Use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to auto generate thumbs for all images. If you ever add a new image size then always resize images again with this plugin.